# Discord Bot cannot access text files

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Long story short, I have been working in a bot for the past month but I had all of my commands on on_message listeners instead of context and command decorators, so I decided to do it properly, in the process of transferring my commands numerous changes have been needed, but this one has me puzzled.

The way I store user information is in text files, unfortunately on the new way of doing things it seems that I cannot access text files anymore, I looked at this code over and over and tried to troubleshoot it by making sure strings aren't empty and such, the more I looked into it the more I realized that there isn't anything wrong with it, based on other information i've looked up online, the only reason I could think of is because code is inside an async function which causes it to not work. It does not throw any exceptions for anyone wondering

If this is indeed the case, what would I have to do to fix it?

Current code:

```
userid = 'userfiles/' + ctx.message.server.id + '/' + ctx.message.author.id + '.txt' #get path based on user ID
try:  
    userfile = open(userid, 'a') #open the file from
    userfile.write(i)
    userfile.close()
except IOError:
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Irrecovarable exception encountered')
    return
```

Comment: Try running the code without the try/except so it gives you the full error message.  Then post that error message here.

Comment: I just did it, it does not give an exception or message, I printed the string to make sure it's not empty and it wasn't

Comment: What is `i`?  Are you trying to open a file that doesn't already exist, or in a directory that hasn't been created?  Do you have any other error handling code that could be catching the error messages before they get to you?

Comment: `i` is the string to be written to the file, I already said that I've printed it to make sure that it it's fine, prior to this code is code that builds the string to be written and does not have any error handling. Here is the whole function code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/imQRazcr) Had to use pastebin as I can't fit the code into my comment